# Set label in color assigned to category in ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, pie-chart

In a pie-chart (S.S.R.S. Report), i am showing labels outside.I want to show the labels in the color of category allotted in pie chart.

Comment: check the data labels properties, you can set how they appear there.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky! According to my personal experience that is not possible, but as alternative you could apply the same color of your categories to the lines of the labels that are outside of the chart area and this is only possible if you adopt the Pie Chart 3D model.
If you are using the simple pie model you can use the lines outside of the chart as well, but you won't be able to put the colors into them and in addition, the size of the chart will be affected by the size of the labels. Instead, if you are using the 3D model it is possible to choose the proportion of the size of the chart in comparison to the labels, ie 70 (chart) and 30 (labels), for instance. Good luck! :)